# How to resolve *url-loader* path?

Tags: webpack

There's a HTML-file deep in the tree structure. It has this line:

```
<img src="../../images/call.svg">
```

How can I tell Webpack to look for this file in `images` folder without using long path like that?
I need any `img` element on any HTML-file located at any position in the tree to resolve to `images` folder, so that I could make something like:

```
<img src="images/call.svg">
```

Here's my configuration file:

```js
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
 entry: './src/app.js',
 output: {
  path: './dist',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
 },
 module: {
  loaders: [
   { 
    test: /\.html$/, 
    loader: "html-loader" 
   },
   {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    loader: 'url'
   }
  ]
 }
};
```

Comment: There's a similar question without an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734132/file-loader-set-root-file-path?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `htmlLoader` property in your webpack config, you can pass a root property to `html-loader`, and use root-relative paths. Then the relative path will be appended to this root property to resolve the absolute path.

For example if you want to provide paths relative to `src` directory:

```js
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.html$/, 
                loader: "html-loader" 
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loader: 'url'
            }
        ]
    },
    htmlLoader: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }
};
```

then you can provide paths relative to `src` directory for example:

```
<img src="/images/call.svg">
```

**notice the leading `/` in front of path**, that's how you tell `html-loader` it's a root-relative path, otherwise it will be still relative to its own context.

Comment: sir, you're awesome! Thank you so much! I love you!

Comment: Glad I could help.